# Prevent ace-editor from rendering binary files

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

From some dynamic data,

sometimes the ace-editor get filled like this

[image: ace]

How can i tell ace not to render binary characters?

In those cases, ace should print like "Binary characters are none of our business."

Comment: We are in 2017, nobody uses ASCII any more. That looks like a picture; do you mean not displaying binary files?

Comment: yes, you got the point,, i want not to display binary files

Comment: check for binary files before setting the value

Comment: i don't get file,  i get a string.

Comment: then test it for \0 , `/\0/.test(string)`